# Target next element with specific class attribute

Tags: jquery

I have a table with a dropdown in one column, and hidden DIVs in the next column. Depending on the dropdown value, only one DIV in next column should show.

Here is the layout I have.
I have been able to target the next `<td>`, but haven't had luck with an actual `<div>` inside a `<td>`.

I am not getting any jquery errors. Thanks!

```
...
<tr>
    <!–– Dropdown column ––>
    <td>
    <select class="dropdown">
        <option value="firstDiv">Show First</option>
        <option value="secondDiv">Show Second</option>
    </select>
    </td>

    <!–– Column with hidden/visible Divs we are targeting ––>
    <td>
        <div class="firstDiv">First Div</div>
        <div class="secondDiv">Second Div</div>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <!–– Dropdown column ––>
    <td>
    <select class="dropdown">
        <option value="firstDiv">Show First</option>
        <option value="secondDiv">Show Second</option>
    </select>
    </td>

    <!–– Column with hidden/visible Divs we are targeting ––>
    <td>
        <div class="firstDiv">First Div</div>
        <div class="secondDiv">Second Div</div>
    </td>
</tr>
...


$('.dropdown').change(function() {
        id = this.id;
        value = $(this).val();

        $(this).closest("td > .firstDiv").next().hide(); //First hide everything, even if already hidden
        $(this).closest("td > .secondDiv").next().hide(); //First hide everything, even if already hidden

        $(this).closest("td > ." + value).next().toggle(); //Show the chosen one
     })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try selecting like this `$(this).closest("tr").find("td .firstDiv").hide()`. This way, you'd find the `tr` element that contains the drop-down, and then you'd find in the same row the desired class inside a `td`.

```js
$(".firstDiv").hide();
$(".secondDiv").hide();

$('.dropdown').change(function() {
        value = $(this).val();
        $(this).closest("tr").find("td .firstDiv").hide(); //First hide everything, even if already hidden
        $(this).closest("tr").find("td .secondDiv").hide(); //First hide everything, even if already hidden

        $(this).closest("tr").find("td ." + value).toggle(); //Show the chosen one
     })
```

```html
<table>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
    <!–– Dropdown column ––>
    <td>
    <select class="dropdown">
        <option value="firstDiv">Show First</option>
        <option value="secondDiv">Show Second</option>
    </select>
    </td>

    <!–– Column with hidden/visible Divs we are targeting ––>
    <td>
        <div class="firstDiv">First Div</div>
        <div class="secondDiv">Second Div</div>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <!–– Dropdown column ––>
    <td>
    <select class="dropdown">
        <option value="firstDiv">Show First</option>
        <option value="secondDiv">Show Second</option>
    </select>
    </td>

    <!–– Column with hidden/visible Divs we are targeting ––>
    <td>
        <div class="firstDiv">First Div</div>
        <div class="secondDiv">Second Div</div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the div `display:none` and use jquery `hide()` and `show()` to display the selected element.In my code i have displayed 'FirstDiv' initially because the default option in select box is 'Show First' or else you can add `display:none` to both div in css. Hope this helps

```js
$('.dropdown').change(function(e){

    $(this).parent().next().find('.'+$(this).val()).show().siblings().hide()

})
```

```css
.secondDiv
{
   display:none;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <!–– Dropdown column ––>
    <td>
    <select class="dropdown">
        <option value="firstDiv">Show First</option>
        <option value="secondDiv">Show Second</option>
    </select>
    </td>

    <!–– Column with hidden/visible Divs we are targeting ––>
    <td>
        <div class="firstDiv">First Div</div>
        <div class="secondDiv">Second Div</div>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <!–– Dropdown column ––>
    <td>
    <select class="dropdown">
        <option value="firstDiv">Show First</option>
        <option value="secondDiv">Show Second</option>
    </select>
    </td>

    <!–– Column with hidden/visible Divs we are targeting ––>
    <td>
        <div class="firstDiv">First Div</div>
        <div class="secondDiv">Second Div</div>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```